# Weird mouse behavior in games (official Steam client)

Tags: mouse, games, steam

I'm playing Counter-Strike Source on KDE Neon 5.21, within official Steam client.
What I noticed is that in game mouse sometimes doesn't react to left/right clicks at all - or the mouse button seems to jam, so the weapon I'm using continues to fire despite I lifted the finger.

Problem is not hardware, as it occurs for both mouses I'm using + doesn't happen when playing the same game in Windows.

Comment: What kind of mouse are you using, wireless or wired? What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: Problem occurs to me with both wired and wireless mouses. 
I'm using latest KDE Neon, and I guess it runs most recent Ubuntu under the hood

Comment: That sounds weird if it happens with a wired mouse too, but I'm not sure KDE Neon is on-topic here.

Comment: Had this previously with Mac OS X. Somehow the window is losing focus temporarily, for me I think it was because of some keyboard shortcut that I didn't know about. When it happened it was possible to Super (aka Win/Cmd) + Tab or click the mouse and it would return to focus. Have you made sure it's not something as simple as that?

Comment: @l3l_aze Yes, I've configured my KDE Neon to ignore all global shortcuts while this app is open. I also tried newer CS:GO recently, and it seems to not have this issue

Comment: Apparently this has been an [issue since at least 2013](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Source-1-Games/issues/112). I don't understand it well personally, but [this Steam Community guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=129836524) claims to be able to help.